# How can I use a breakpoint and debug launch configuration for multi-root workspaces with Typescript files in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm not sure how to debug typescript file. Debugging from multi-root-workspaces does not seem to work.

[workspace folder image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USFPS.png)

I encountered this warning when I add and hit the breakpoint.

**Unbound breakpoint**

Some of your your breakpoint could not be set. If you're having an issue you can troubleshoot your launch configuration.

[I created Launch.json for MicroserviceA, MicroserviceB and Workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1HAe.png)

[my.code-workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nITw2.png)

[tsconfig.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcXHL.png)

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post a small example reproducing the issue. It might seem like a lot of text, but it clears up a few possible reasons for this issue.

Comment: Also, your `./vscode/launch.json` file would be useful as well.